# Debian 8.9 restore deleted but locked files

Tags: linux, debian, restore, rm

I accidently ran rm -R /home/. My Homefolder contained several disks of virtual machines which were in use at this moment. I also got the error, that some files could not have been deleted. Nevertheless, I cannot access the files in my /home/ folder anymore.

Looking for a solution I found out, that I could try to restore the files with cp /proc/PID/fd/12 /target/.

Now I am a little bit confused - as the virtual machine is still working it probably writes to the disk which I am trying to recover.

Will I have inconsistencies in those disks? Or do you maybe have another hint?

I appreciate every kind of help!

Thank you very much!

Comment: No, the stated method should be file: on POSIX systems, an opened file descriptor counts as a reference (link) to the file, so the space occupied by such file is left on the filesystem intact; it just has no names on the filesystem itself to access it.

Comment: You could open a 2nd reference to the nameless file (eg: `sleep 99999 < /proc/PID/fd/12 &`) to avoid its deletion and then freeze or stop the VM, to be sure there's no inconsistency in the cp backup. Of course if you stop the VM, no mistake is allowed after (and before: in the command used to keep a reference)

Comment: Thank you for this great advice! I copied some VMs without the second reference and the suspend and some with the method you describe. Both methods worked fine, although some of the machines had to restore some blocks with the help of the journal while booting. Probably because there were writes during copying the file. However, I could restore all VirtualMachines. @A.B. if you like you can write an answer, so I can mark it as such. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Done, added an answer, with some explanations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A file on a given filesystem is referenced by its *index node* aka *inode*. As long as there are references to this inode, be it on disk (linked as filename(s), can exist multiple times) or "in memory" (open file descriptor aka fd, mount point, mmaped ...) the file and its data stays on disk. When there's no more reference to it, it's then really deleted and the space reclaimed. When the disk reference becomes 0, even if there are still references "in memory", there's no way to relink it with a new name, because there's no kernel API for the user allowing for example to link an inode referenced by its fd or the inode value itself, it's only available by filename (unless on an adequate filesystem using [dark and dangerous magic](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/debugfs.8.html): `debugfs ln`).

The Linux kernel still provides some facilities to access this file with the `/proc` pseudo filesystem. Each open file in `/proc/PID/fd/` is displayed as a symlink pointing to a file. The file's name is cosmetic information (and can be wrong when the file was unlinked), but the file itself is to be considered as *the* actual file, as seen by the kernel.

So for this case, as long as the VM is running, the file used as the VM's disk backend still exists, but can't be relinked on disk. What can easily be done is to copy it with an adequate command, for example:

`cp --sparse=always /proc/PID/fd/12 > backup`.

Because the VM is running, doing this might create an inconsistent result: the filesystem (inside the file) can change during the copy and can become inconsistent and corrupted. So either freeze the VM if its hypervisor allows it *and* doesn't close the VM's disk file when frozen, either add a new reference to the nameless file and stop the VM. If you don't want to take any chance, add the reference anyway before freezing it. Any command reading the file and lasting long enough is fine. For example:

```
$ sleep 99999 < /proc/PID/fd/12 &
[1] 12087
```

You should now verify that `/proc/12087/fd/0` is referencing the same `... (deleted)` file.

The VM can now be frozen or even stopped (but won't be able to start again then). Since there's no more activity on the filesystem, the backup should be consistent (with filesystem journal recovery if simply frozen). Using `cp` with option `--sparse=always` appears to be a good choice if the VM's disk file was "lazy" provisioned and mostly empty, to use less space.